# Diferencias entre las distintas versiones de PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

He estado buscando las principales diferencias entre las versiones 10, 11, 12 de PostgreSQL pero no logro encontrar algo realmente útil
¿Alguien sabe cuales son las principales diferencias entre estas versiones? ¿Que tiene una que la otra no tenga? ¿o saben donde puedo encontrar dicha información?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Creo que aquí tienes una muy buena documentación https://www.postgresql.org/about/featurematrix/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

También puedes consultar los comunicados de prensa de cada una de las versiones (se encuentran disponibles en varios idiomas), en los mismos encontrarás enlaces que llevan a páginas con mayor detalle de información como "Notas de la versión" y "Qué hay de nuevo en Postgresql X" (pero la mayoría en ingles):

- [Postgresql 10](https://www.postgresql.org/about/press/presskit10/es/)
- [Postgresql 11](https://www.postgresql.org/about/press/presskit11/es/)
- [Postgresql 12](https://www.postgresql.org/about/press/presskit12/es/)
- [Postgresql 13](https://www.postgresql.org/about/press/presskit13/es/)
- [Postgresql 14](https://www.postgresql.org/about/press/presskit14/es/)